# CultureInfo.Region works in Immediate window, not in code

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

I tested this on both .Net 4.0 and .Net 4.0 CP, same result.

This line:
`global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us").Region`

If I type it in Visual Studio (C#), then Visual Studio tells me "Region" isn't valid.
If I type the same line in Immediate window during a breakpoint it is fully valid and returns data as expected. And from what I can see "Region" is not in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx).

Obviously two different objects for some reason.
Why? Whats happening here? Why is reality not consistent? I get scared!
(More seriously, I see behaviour I don't understand so I'd like to understand it.)

Immediate window returns:

```
global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us").Region
{US}
    CurrencyEnglishName: "US Dollar"
    CurrencyNativeName: "US Dollar"
    CurrencySymbol: "$"
    DisplayName: "United States"
    EnglishName: "United States"
    GeoId: 244
    IsMetric: false
    ISOCurrencySymbol: "USD"
    Name: "US"
    NativeName: "United States"
    ThreeLetterISORegionName: "USA"
    ThreeLetterWindowsRegionName: "USA"
    TwoLetterISORegionName: "US"
```

While Visual Studio go all red on me:
[image: Visual Studio don't recognize CutlureInfo.Region]

Comment: Just a small sidenote: I'm not only looking for a different/right way to do this, I would like to know why Immediate and code differ.

Comment: The compiler is right of course. Seems like the Imm window adds some smarts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Region is a non-public property of the CultureInfo class. It seems that the immediate window has access to it.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed in Reflector that its defined as: `private RegionInfo Region { get; }`

Answer (score 0):

Current RegionInfo is available using

```
RegionInfo.CurrentRegion
```